# android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and android:gravity="bottom" however xml item still appears at top

Tags: android, xml

I'm not sure exactly why this is happening but I've specified android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and android:gravity="bottom" in my (Android) xml layout however the item (HorizontalScrollView containing carousel1) still appears at the top of the layout.

I'm not sure exactly what is wrong in this instance.

Thanks in advance.

Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wefnn.png

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="00dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_faded"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/main_header_selector"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/carousel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you include how this layout is being inflated? Is this the only layout being used to reproduce the image you have linked? It appears you have another layout (because you reference an id of 'imageView1' that doesn't exist here, for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the parent LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and in the linearlayout of ScrollView i removed android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and just added android:layout_gravity="bottom". I hope this will help you. Here is the xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="00dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_faded"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/main_header_selector"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/carousel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `HorizontalScrollView`, don't use `layout_alignParentBottom`, use `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`. [See LinearLayout.LayoutParams reference guide.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity)

`LinearLayout` uses `layout_gravity` for its children, `RelativeLayout` uses `layout_alignX` where X is top, bottom, etc. If you wanted, you could keep it as `layout_alignParentBottom` but the parent of your HorizontalScrollView would need to be a `RelativeLayout`. Either solution should accomplish the same effect.

Comment: I tried as you suggested and it still appears at the top of the screen... 
http://pastebin.com/WNLQbS2u

Comment: You will also need to change the `layout_alignParentBottom` in the LinearLayout as well as the ScrollView `layout_below` both to `layout_gravity="bottom"`. I will double check to see if that structure will yield the correct output and edit my answer.

Comment: I tried those too... it's still appearing at the top for some strange reason. 
http://pastebin.com/NSma1kbf

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="00dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_faded"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_faded"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/carousel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I just did (thank you!) but the scrollview/carousel is still appearing at the top of the layout...